# Amcharts fill the circle with an image

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I'm working on a sample using amcharts library. I want the image to fill the red circle

here is what I tried to do

```
  icon.circle.strokeWidth = 0;
  icon.image.properties.width = "100%";
  icon.image.properties.height = "100%";
  icon.image.properties.maxWidth = "100%";
  icon.image.properties.maxHeight = "100%";
```

Here is the full code snippet uploaded to [codePen](https://codepen.io/fayekramzy/pen/pojGMKr?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I state I'm not proficient with amcharts.

In your example I changed from

```
icon.circle.radius = am4core.percent(100);
icon.image.properties.scale = 1;
```

to

```
icon.circle.radius = am4core.percent(350);
icon.image.properties.scale = 3.5;
```

and I obtained almost requested result, with a nice red border, increasing the scale to about 3.8 the image covers all the red surface.

It works even without.

```
icon.image.properties.width = "100%";
icon.image.properties.height = "100%";
icon.image.properties.maxWidth = "100%";
icon.image.properties.maxHeight = "100%";
```

Probably in your final application of the concept you'll need to perform some more computation to get the required scale for the two options I changed... I can't say.

Hope to gave you some ideas.